# Program won't enter try block inside while loop

Tags: java, exception, loops, while-loop, try-catch

I am trying to write a program for school. The assignment is to loop and ask the user to enter files. When either a file is not found or the user exits out the loop (in my case, they click cancel on a joptionpane) data for each of the files is output. So far this is my code:

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Lists to hold file data
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> numChars = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> numWords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> numLines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String inFile;

    while ( (inFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a file name:")) != null) {

        // Create new file object instance
        File file = new File(inFile);

        try {
            fileNames.add(inFile);  // File name as a string
            // Pass file objects
            numChars.add( getNumChars(file));
            numWords.add( getNumWords(file));
            numLines.add( getNumLines(file));
            System.out.println("entered try block");
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find file: " + inFile);
            // break out the loop and display data
            break;
        }
    }   // end while

    if (numChars.size() > 0)
        showFileData(fileNames, numChars, numWords, numLines);

    System.out.println("Program ended");

}

private static void showFileData(List<String> fileNames,
        List<Integer> numChars, List<Integer> numWords,
        List<Integer> numLines) {
    for (int i=0;i<numChars.size();i++) {
        System.out.println("Data for: " + fileNames.get(i));
        System.out.println("Number of characters: " + numChars.get(i));
        System.out.println("Number of words: " + numWords.get(i));
        System.out.println("Number of lines: " + numLines.get(i));
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    }

}

private static int getNumLines(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int c = 0;
    Scanner f = new Scanner(file);
    while(f.hasNextLine()) {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}

private static int getNumWords(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int c = 0;
    Scanner f = new Scanner(file);
    while (f.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] w = f.nextLine().split(" ");
        c += w.length;
    }
    return c;
}

private static int getNumChars(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner f = new Scanner(file);
    int c = 0;
    String line;
    while(f.hasNextLine()) {
        line = f.nextLine();
        String[] s = line.split(" ");
        for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
            c += s[i].length();
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

When I run the program, if I press cancel, it exits the loop and displays the stuff at the end like it's supposed to. If I enter a file that doesn't exist, it works how it's supposed to. The only time it doesn't work is when I enter a file that DOES exist, it doesn't pop up another input dialog. In fact, it doesn't seem to enter the try block. Have I set my program up correctly?

Comment: print some output to the screen at the beginning of the try block and immediately before the try block.  That way you can track your program's execution and see what happens when you enter in a correct filename.  A useful thing to print is the `inFile` variable, just to make sure that it is what you think it is

Comment: You could use File.isFile() instead of using an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in `getNumLines()`.    You need a `f.nextLine()` in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

@DomV is correct, you have an infinite loop in your getNumLines() function.

You end up opening the file and reading through it three times once to get the number of lines once to get the number of words and once for characters.  Maybe you want to find a way to minimize those expensive disk operations.  Doing this will also force you to examine more closely what you're doing while reading through the file and solve the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The application loops forever in this method:

```
private static int getNumLines(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int c = 0;
    Scanner f = new Scanner(file);
    while(f.hasNextLine()) {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Note the while() loop: you check if there are additional lines in the file, but do not read any data from the file - thus, hasNextLine() continously returns true.

Answer (score 0):

in getNumLines:

```
 while(f.hasNextLine()) {
  c++;
 }
```

Will always be true, change it for

```
    private static int getNumLines(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int c = 0;
    Scanner f = new Scanner(file);
     while(f.hasNextLine()) {
        f.nextLine();
        c++;
     }
     return c;
    }
```